# Visual Studio 2010 designer generating invalid code

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, designer

This is a first for me, I thought I was completely losing my mind. I have a simple winform application to which I add a datagridview. I set the datasource for the dgv, using the same source I've used in half a dozen other projects, and configure the grid the way I want it. There is nothing else on the form at this point except for the grid, and the project now contains a data set, a binding source, and a table adapter. Great. However, the code generated by the designer in doing this is invalid and is causing compile errors, telling me that the data set table adapters object and the data set itself does not exist.

If I go into the designer where the compile error is I see the following lines:

```
this.tILEDataSet = new ImageEdit.TILEDataSet();
this.logosTableAdapter = new ImageEdit.TILEDataSetTableAdapters.LogosTableAdapter();
```

ImageEdit is the class to which I have added this bound control. If I remove the "ImageEdit.", the code compiles and works perfectly. Of course, since this is a designer generated file, as soon as I make any other changes, it reverts back to the code in question.

I did this three times, with three different projects, twice starting from scratch with a fresh instance of visual studio.

What could be going wrong to cause this to happen, and is there a fix, other than manually editing a designer file, which I never like to do?

I did not change anything, everything was generated by the designer. Both the namespace and class were created as ImageEdit. The designer contains the following definitions:
    private TILEDataSet tILEDataSet;
    private TILEDataSetTableAdapters.LogosTableAdapter logosTableAdapter;

The designer class definition does derive from global::System.ComponentModel.Component:

```
public partial class LogosTableAdapter : global::System.ComponentModel.Component {
    .
.
.
```

Thanks again for any insight.

Comment: What is the compiler error (exactly)? Therein will be the answer to the question.

Comment: The exact error(s):      The type name 'TILEDataSetTableAdapters' does not exist in the type 'ImageEdit.ImageEdit' 
The type name 'TILEDataSet' does not exist in the type 'ImageEdit.ImageEdit'

Comment: Did you alter the namespace that `ImageEdit` is in after using the designer to add the dataset and adapter? Usually the designer produces very verbose type names, those do not look verbose (global:: is missing). We would need to see both the file where `ImageEdit` is defined and the entire designer produced file to make any further guesses.

Comment: I did not change anything, everything was generated by the designer. Both the namespace and class were created as ImageEdit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you have several members in your solution named `ImageEdit`, whether they be namespaces, classes, or other members.  In Microsoft's [Guidelines for Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx), and in particular, [Names of Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx) they recommend:

> **Do prefix namespace names with a company name to prevent namespaces from different companies from having the same name and prefix.**
>
> **Do not use the same name for a namespace and a type in that namespace. For example, do not use Debug for a namespace name and also provide a class named Debug in the same namespace. Several compilers require such types to be fully qualified.**
>
> **Do not give the same name to types in namespaces within a single application model.**
>   For example, if you were writing a library of special controls to be used by Windows forms application developers, you should not introduce a type named Checkbox because a type with this name already exists for the application model (CheckBox).

The second point alone should fix your issue.  Using the first point, a company name as part of the namespace, will cause the code generator to provide a more concise name for your objects, such as:

```
this.tILEDataSet = new MyCompany.ImageEdit.TILEDataSet();
this.logosTableAdapter = new MyCompany.ImageEdit.TILEDataSetTableAdapters.LogosTableAdapter();
```

Comment: That took care of it, thank you so much. I used Refactor to change the namespace and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

This could also happen if, in any configuration that request a namespace, you type the same name or namespace as your project:

[image]

This results in a conflict with your existing namespace:

[image]

Just use any other name other than the namespace you already have in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I came across it when I was having the same issue.  I think the reason my generated code was causing issues was because I created the form and added the datagridview and linked to the data source all before saving the new Form.  If I created the Form, Saved it, added the DataGridView, saved the form, then linked the data source, and saved it, I no longer get the issue.  Probably something to do with the code generator not being able to see unsaved code.